# PDF quality for PNG files using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I´ve been using R and ggplot2 for a while, and if I am to create graphs and plots in a png format with a good quality, I always have to produce a pdf and then do a screenshot. I´ve also tried to create a png with the RStudio function, but the quality is considerably lower (even though it is png, tiff, etc., it doesn´t matter). Here you see an example of it with the exact same dimensions:

[image: PDF screenshot]

[image: PNG image]

Comment: You can save as SVG and then convert the SVG to PNG with the **rsvg** package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually export our figures in vector format (PDF, SVG), to be able to edit them afterwards. However, these plots might result in large files. In this case we export them as high-res PNGs, by setting the dpi to 1200.

```
ggsave("plot.png", dpi = 1200)
```

Comment: The problem is that know the file is too big (more than 2900 kB) when the pdf is 24, and when converted into a png online, its weight is 186 (way lower). Is there other approach to avoid those large files?

Comment: All I can think of is using high quality JPGs then, which are more compressed than PNGs.

Comment: It´s strange then, because when using the code ```ggsave("plot.jpg", width=20, height=14, units="in",dpi = 1200)``` the figure obtained is 17000 kB, much larger than the png or the pdf (with the same dimensions).

Comment: Apparently JPEGs can have larger file sizes in certain situations. You can still lower the dpi settings in your PNGs to find the sweet spot. Or maybe something like `webshot2::shrink` hellps?